# Update column in Table A from Table B where value does not exist in distinct result from Table B in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables both containing a column called `domain`.

Table A

```
|id | domain        |
|-------------------|
| 1 | google.com    |
| 2 | google.com    |
| 3 | yahoo.com     |
| 4 | microsoft.com |
| 5 | microsoft.com |
| 6 | slack.com     |
| 7 | loom.com      |
| 8 | loom.com      |
```

Table B

```
|id | domain        |
|-------------------|
| 1 | google.com    |
| 2 | yahoo.com     |
| 3 | microsoft.com |
```

I want to add rows to `Table B` for values in `Table A` that:

1. Don't exist in `Table B`
2. Are distinct in `Tabel A`

So in the use case above, `Table B` would end up like this:

```
|id | domain        |
|-------------------|
| 1 | google.com    |
| 2 | yahoo.com     |
| 3 | microsoft.com |
| 4 | slack.com     |
| 5 | loom.com      |
```

Here is where I'm at with the query, which doesn't work obviously:

`UPDATE tableb tb SET tb.domain = ta.domain WHERE tb.domain NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(domain) FROM tablea) ta LIMIT 1`

Comment: I think your expected output should _not_ have `loom.com`, because this domain is not distinct in the A table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, I mean I only want one of each domain from Table A, so there are two cases of loom.com so i only want to add it 1 time to Table B since it doesn't exist in Table B yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exists logic:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (domain)   -- assuming id is auto increment
SELECT DISTINCT domain
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tableb b WHERE b.domain = a.domain);
```

The exists clause ensures that the domain from A table does not already exist in the B table.  We select distinct domains from the A table to avoid inserting the same domain more than once.

Comment: Does this cover the second condition, the records should be distinct in table a

Comment: @Deepak Please rephrase your language.  The requirement is _not_ that the records are "distinct" in the A table.  Your requirement is just that you don't want to insert the same domain from table A into B more than once, should this domain occur multiple times in the A table.  My answer covers this by selecting only distinct domains from the A table.

Comment: I was referring to the condition `2. Are distinct in Tabel A`. Yes, the solution works

Comment: `loom.com` is _not_ distinct in the A table, it appears in duplicate...just using the correct language